# How to disable Emacs bidi?

Tags: unicode, display, bidirectional-support

I want to disable Emacs from ever displaying text right-to-left (i.e. ignore Unicode control sequences to change text orientation). How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

I think @Dan's answer is correct. But do consult the Elisp manual node he pointed to ([Bidirectional Display](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Bidirectional-Display.html)). But consult *first* the **Emacs** manual node [Bidirectional Editing](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Bidirectional-Editing.html).

However, I also think that the Emacs maintainer (Eli) has recommended against setting variable `bidi-display-reordering` to `nil`. I used to do that, but I switched to this (which I think Eli recommended at some point):

```lisp
(setq-default bidi-paragraph-direction 'left-to-right)
```

You might try that instead. Since I've switched to doing this, and it seems to do the job - reduces or removes the (incredible) slowdown I experienced with buffers that display arbitrary Unicode chars. (I don't have a need to *edit* bidirectional text, but I provide some help commands that can display arbitrary Unicode chars - e.g. library [Apropos Unicode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AproposUnicode) ([`apu.el](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/apu.el)).)

You might also want to pose your question to mailing list help-gnu-emacs@gnu.org. Eli and others who are experts on this might have better or more up-to-date recommendations or advice. (I'm no authority on bidi etc.)

Comment: The settings doesn't work. I keep seeing text RTL. `bidi-paragraph-direction` only sets the base orientation AFAIU. Once it sees an unicode control sequence it'll use that. I'll try the mailing list. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Set the variable `bidi-display-reordering` to `nil`.

Here's the docstring:

> Documentation:
> Non-nil means reorder bidirectional text for display in the visual order.
> Setting this to nil is intended for use in debugging the display code.
> Don’t set to nil in normal sessions, as that is not supported.
> See also ‘bidi-paragraph-direction’; setting that non-nil might
> speed up redisplay.

I found out about this variable in
the
[Bidirectional display node of the Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Bidirectional-Display.html) after
doing a web search for ["emacs bidi"](https://www.google.com/search?channel=cus5&client=firefox-b-1-d&q=emacs+bidi).

Comment: It doesn't work. Open file with RTL text and I still see the text RTL.